# FOR loop in WITH statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've created a WITH statement such as:

```
 WITH data AS(
   SELECT COUNT (*) as a, E.b as b
   FROM         table1 C
   JOIN         table2 D
   ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
   JOIN         table3 E
   ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
   WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4
   GROUP BY     E.b
   ORDER BY     E.b)
```

And i want to use it in a for loop like this:

```
BEGIN
FOR x IN 1..100 LOOP
{ WITH data AS(
       SELECT COUNT (*) as a, E.b as b
       FROM         table1 C
       JOIN         table2 D
       ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
       JOIN         table3 E
       ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
       WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4
       GROUP BY     E.b
       ORDER BY     E.b)}
END LOOP;
END;
```

But oracle says that i need into in this statement. What should i do? Should i use a cursor? How would it look like?

Comment: What exactly is this suppose to do? seems like its suppose to just run 100 times

Comment: Yes it suppose to just run 100 times because i need to check running time for this statement

Comment: Try deleting the with part, why do you need it? you dont use it any where

Comment: I use it i the next part of the code. I've never used WITH in for loop and therefore is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you simply need to run 100 times the same query, consider that however you have to use an `INTO` clause, no matter if you use the `WITH` or not.

You may try this way:

```
DECLARE
    type tab_number is table of number;
    vA tab_number;
    vB tab_number;
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
       WITH data AS(
           SELECT COUNT (*) as a, E.b as b
           FROM         table1 C
           JOIN         table2 D
           ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
           JOIN         table3 E
           ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
           WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4
           GROUP BY     E.b
           ORDER BY     E.b
       )
       SELECT A, B
       BULK COLLECT INTO vA, vB
       FROM DATA;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

or even without `WITH`:

```
DECLARE
    type tab_number is table of number;
    vA tab_number;
    vB tab_number;
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
       SELECT COUNT (*) as a, E.b as b
       BULK COLLECT INTO vA, vB
       FROM         table1 C
       JOIN         table2 D
       ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
       JOIN         table3 E
       ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
       WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4
       GROUP BY     E.b
       ORDER BY     E.b;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Notice that in these examples we use a `BULK COLLECT`, given tha your query may return more than one row.
If you simply need one row, you can remove the `GROUP BY` clause and try something like the following:

```
DECLARE
    vA NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
       SELECT COUNT (*) as A
       INTO vA
       FROM         table1 C
       JOIN         table2 D
       ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
       JOIN         table3 E
       ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
       WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Please consider that this may not be the best way to check the performance of a query: after the first run, data may already have been cached, so the following runs may be faster

Answer (score 2):

> I need to check running time for this statement

You're assuming that the `WITH` part runs independently of the actual query that *uses* it, which is usually not correct.  The `WITH` will get compiled along with the part that uses it into one execution plan. If you want to check the `WITH` section by itself, then just take out the `WITH` line and run the `SELECT within it.

However, It would be more accurate to run the *entire* query, or get a better SQL profiling tool.